# How to specify a type parameter I do not know

Tags: generics, kotlin

I have reduced my problem to the following minimal demonstration:

```
interface Property<T : Comparable<T>>

fun <T : Comparable<T>> parsePropertyValue(property: Property<T>, value: String): T = TODO()

fun test() {
    val property: Property<*> = TODO()
    val value = parsePropertyValue(property, "test")
}
```

The call to `parsePropertyValue` does not compile, with the error message "Cannot infer type parameter T". The equivalent Java code compiles without problems:

```
interface JavaProperty<T extends Comparable<T>> { }

class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JavaProperty<?> property = null;
        Comparable<?> value = parsePropertyValue(property, "test")
    }

    private static <T extends Comparable<T>> T parsePropertyValue(JavaProperty<T> property, String value) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

How can achieve something similar in Kotlin? Please note that the `Property` interface in this example is from an external library and I cannot change it.

As per request, a little bigger example:

```
interface Property<T : Comparable<T>> {
    fun parseValue(value: String): T
}

interface PropertyStore {
    fun <T : Comparable<T>> setValue(property: Property<T>, value: T)
    fun <T : Comparable<T>> getValue(property: Property<T>): T
}

fun main() {
    val property: Property<*> = TODO()
    val unparsedValue: String = TODO()
    val propertyStore: PropertyStore = TODO() 
}

fun <T : Comparable<T>> parseAndApplyValue(propertyStore: PropertyStore, property: Property<T>, unparsedValue: String) {
    val parsedValue: T = property.parseValue(unparsedValue)
    propertyStore.setValue(property, parsedValue)
}
```

Comment: Use the `Any` type.

Comment: And how, exactly? `Property<Any>` is not valid, because `Any` is not a subtype of `Comparable<Any>` and as such cannot be used for `T` in `Property<T>`.

Comment: Can you please provide a meaningful example showing what you're trying to achieve? Right now it seems to me that Kotlin is perfectly justified in not compiling your program.

Comment: Not quite sure what is not meaningful about my example. I am getting some `Property<T>`, for which I do not know what `T` is. I am now trying to materialize that `T` by passing the property to a function, so that I can actually work with the property. I provided a bit of a bigger example though.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's not compiling is because `Property` has to be parametrized by something that is `Comparable` and `*` is not.

Any chance you can change

`val property: Property<*> = TODO()`

to

`val property: Property<Int> = TODO()`

or something else that is `Comparable`? That will get your code compiling.

Comment: Well, that is exactly my problem, I do not know the type. I only know it is "something that is Comparable". The best way I found to express that is `*`.

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ IDEA was hinting you at the answer, though at the wrong place:

[image]

Notice the grey underline? That's an inspection, telling you to add the 'in' variance modifier:

[image]

After changing the code to `interface Property<in T : Comparable<T>>`, everything compiles.

You can read more about variance here: http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I cannot add the `in` variance here for two reasons:
1) `Property` is not part of my code, it comes from a library that I cannot control.
2) Even if it was part of my code, there are methods in `Property` that return `T`, so I could not make `T` `in`, even if I wanted to.

Comment: @diesieben07 Is `parsePropertyValue` part of your code? If yes, can you change it to `fun <T : Comparable<T>> parsePropertyValue(property: Property<in T>, value: String)`?

Comment: Please see the bigger example in my post for a more accurate view of what I am trying to do. As you can there I unfortunately need a `Property<T>`, not a `Property<in T>`.

Comment: I think I understand. In your bigger example, can you pull out your code into a separate method and parametrize the method with `T`?

Comment: No, I cannot. I am deserializing the properties from a network stream. The property store gives me a `Property<*>` for a property name (a string). I then need to deserialize that property and set it's value on the property store. But I can only do that if I get a `Property<T>`.

Comment: Alright. I suspect this is an actual compiler issue. I've opened https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-18002 to track it.